# Serial-Parallel Execution of multiple AsyncTasks in Quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net

I can do this with Task class in C# 4.0 but I want to give a chance to Quartz.net framework.

- Task A (Runs every Sunday)

  - Task A.1
  - Task A.11 .. Task A.1n (Runs after Task A.1 is completed, n is set after Task A.1)

There is 3 exceptions:

- RetryCurrentSubTaskException
- CancelCurrentSubTaskException ( Main Task still can be completed)
- CancelAllTasksException (Critic exception)

How can I achieve this with quartz.net or any other lightweight scheduling framework?
(persistance layer is Sql Server)

Comment: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/faq.html#howtochainjobs :(